# python 3 How to set html or txt files from ANSI to UTF-8 on windows 8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have some ANSI encoded html and txt files, and I want to turn them to UTF-8. So I read them, write the str in UTF-8 ,and save them in a new folder. I tried this:

**It is best that changing the file's encoding directly, not creating new files**

```
import os  
from os.path import join, getsize  

cp=os.getcwd()+'\\regis'
os.mkdir(cp)
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\Nan\Documents\myauth\customauth\templates\registration'):
    for name in files:
        if os.path.splitext(name)[1][1:] in ('html','txt'):
            p=join(root, name)
            s=open(p).read()
            with open(join(cp,name),'w',encoding='u8') as f:
                f.write(s)
```

But when I check (open it in windows notepad, and choose to save as, you can see the encoding)the new files, it is still ANSI encoded, as you can see from the picture:
[image]

So, what should I do now?

Comment: The encoding shows the current encoding of the file. Select `UTF-8` from the dropdown and Save. You may try to use Notepad instead of creating any program. lol

Comment: I know that way. but when there are hundreds of files, it is hard.

Comment: Does the file contain non-ASCII characters? If not, Notepad may guess it is ANSI even if you correctly converted to UTF-8.

Comment: @Janne Karila Even if it is all-ASCII characters, the problem still exists.

Comment: If the file is all ASCII, a UTF-8-encoded copy is identical to the ASCII original.